# Copy specific column data from one table to another table column? (Wordpress PhPMyAdmin)

Tags: php, mysql

Been googling, testing and searching for hours to no avail...I'm hoping someone here can help me with what I presume is a fairly simple SQL command, but I'm very basic about it and just getting errors.

My situation is as follows:
I need to take certain row data from wp_postmeta table and stuff it into certain row data into wp_posts. I'm migrating some 50,000 orders from drupal to wordpress, but due to weirdness, order #'s don't match up.

What I am looking to do is copy the **meta_value** in the **wp_postmeta** table, but only where **meta_key** **LIKE** "**_fgd2wp_old_uc_order_id**"

Then take this specific query and dump it into **wp_posts table**, into the **ID** column, but only where **post_type LIKE shop_order**.

I can find the data I want through the below search queries...but unsure how to copy. Tried and failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

SELECT `meta_value` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%old_uc_order_id%'
SELECT `ID` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` LIKE 'shop_order'

Tried this command...but it errors saying WHERE isn't expected. Not sure how to specify what i need?

INSERT INTO wp_posts (`ID`)
WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
SELECT
`meta_value`
WHERE meta_key = '_fgd2wp_old_uc_order_id'
FROM wp_postmeta;

Comment: I think you're looking for a multi-table `UPDATE` rather than `INSERT`.  What's the relationship between the two tables?  (ie, for a given value in `wp_postmeta`, how do you know which row to update in `wp_posts`?)

Answer (score 0):

try this
INSERT INTO target_table (`column1`, `column2`)
SELECT
`column1`,
`column2`
FROM source_table

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired migration of data from the wp_postmeta table to the wp_posts table, you can use the following SQL query:`INSERT INTO wp_posts (ID) SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '_fgd2wp_old_uc_order_id' AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type LIKE 'shop_order' AND ID = wp_postmeta.post_id );`